# why does rtsp stream in vlc takes less cpu load than python opencv rtsp?

Tags: vlc, python3, opencv, rtsp

Even though both of the applications are built using same opencv backend, why does the vlc player take lesser load (almost half the load) than a python opencv application to stream the same rtsp video from server

Comment: VLC uses Video Acceleration via VA-API. Please install `vainfo` and check the output of `vainfo`. Also you can try to view console output `libva info: ...` of `vlc /path/to/video.avi` (where `/path/to/video.avi` is the real path to video). Not sure about opencv.